# How to pass value from URL as an argument to ColdFusion function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, jquery-ajax

I am using JQuery and AJAX along with ColdFusion. I have some value in the URL `http://mysitedomain.com/something/page.cfm?x=229` I want this value of `x` as an argument to my ColdFusion function.

Can somebody please tell me how can I pass value of `x` in URL as an argument to my ColdFusion function using AJAX or any other way?

I don't know how it works but still I tried doing this:
AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'SomePathTocfc?method=getsomething&x='+x,
    async: true,
    success: function(result){
        document.getElementById('abc').value = "My Text Input";
    }
});
```

ColdFusion function:

```
<cffunction name="getsomething" access="remote" output="true">
   <cfargument name="x" type="string" required="true">
      <cfquery name="getReq" datasource="#application.dbsrc#" result =result>
          Select * from TableName 
          Where 
          <cfif  isDefined("arguments.x")  >
          x = #arguments.x#
          </cfif>
      </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: You have posted 2 different methods of calling your ColdFusion page. First to a CFM page with an argument in the URL `http://mysitedomain.com/something/page.cfm?x=229`. In your CFM page you would reference that argument as `url.x`. Second example is calling a CFC from JavaScript. What you have given here looks okay to me. I think that should work. What is the error you are getting? By the way, NEVER trust input parameters and place them directly in your query like this `x = #arguments.x#`. You need to sanitize that value first. Use `queryparam` always.

Comment: BTW, your function isn't going to return anything

Comment: @JamesAMohler yes. I am going to add a return statement over there but currently I am facing an issue with arg x.

Comment: @Miguel-F Thanks for your response. I am getting an error saying x is not defined. In my page.cfm page I am doing <cfif isDefined ("url.x")> <cfset x= url.x> </cfif> is this correct?

Comment: now I am getting "undefined" as a return value from my function, any guesses why?

Comment: As James already pointed out, your function is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

just use `<cfargument name="inparam" type="struct">` and you will get the url value as a structure and you can use it and do a `<cfdump var="#arguments#">` and you will see your passed parameters, you can use them like this

```
<cffunction name="getsomething" access="remote" output="true">
   <cfargument name="inParam" type="struct" required="false">
      <cfquery name="getReq" datasource="#application.dbsrc#" result =result>
          Select * from TableName 
          Where 1=1 
<cfif inParam.keyExists('x')>
         and x = <cfqueryparam sqltype="integer" value="#inparam.x#">
</cfif>
          
      </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I am getting "undefined" as a return value from my function, any guesses why?

Comment: did u used <cfreturn getReq>, it will return query results

Comment: and is X a column in your database table TableName

Comment: You also don't need `output="true"` nor do you need `result =result`